# empty data in views.py with threads in django app

Tags: python, django, multithreading, queue

I have a Django app where I'm initializing generative and document retrieval models. I want to dedicate a thread to the generative model as it uses GPU. Below is my apps.py:

```
import atexit
import threading
import time
import torch
import os
import pickle
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from haystack.nodes import EmbeddingRetriever, PromptNode, PromptTemplate, AnswerParser
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig
from queue import Queue

class ChatbotConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'chatbot'
    generative_queue = Queue(maxsize=1)  # Create a queue for generative pipeline requests
    document_queue = Queue(maxsize=10)
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    session_data = {}
    generative_data= {}
    models_initialized = False  # Flag to track if models have been initialized
    gen_models_initialized = False

    session_lock = threading.Lock()  # Lock for session management
    generative_data_lock = threading.Lock()
    processing_complete_event = threading.Event()
    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.models_initialized = False

    def ready(self):
        # Register resource cleanup for application exit
        atexit.register(self.cleanup_resources)

        # Create a thread for processing generative pipeline requests
        generative_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.generative_thread)
        generative_thread.daemon = True
        generative_thread.start()

        # Create a thread for concurrent document retrieval
        document_retrieval_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.document_retrieval_thread)
        document_retrieval_thread.daemon = True
        document_retrieval_thread.start()

    def cleanup_resources(self):
        self.deallocate_gpu_memory()

    def deallocate_gpu_memory(self):
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    def generative_thread(self):
        while True:
            session_id, query, pipeline_type, last_activity = self.generative_queue.get()
            if pipeline_type == 'generative':
                self.process_generative_session(query)
            # Signal that processing is complete for this session
            self.processing_complete_event.set()
            # Reset the event after processing is complete
            self.processing_complete_event.clear()

    def document_retrieval_thread(self):
        while True:
            session_id, pipeline_type, last_activity = self.document_queue.get()
            if pipeline_type == 'document_search':
                self.process_document_retrieval(session_id, last_activity)

            # Signal that processing is complete for this session
            self.processing_complete_event.set()
            # Reset the event after processing is complete
            self.processing_complete_event.clear()

        def process_document_retrieval(self, session_id, last_activity):
    # Use session_id to access session data
    session_data = self.session_data.get(session_id, {})

    if len(session_data) > 0:
        if self.models_initialized is True:
            self.load_doc_search_models_from_session(session_id)
        else:
            self.initialize_doc_search_models(session_id, last_activity)

    elif len(session_data) == 0:
        self.initialize_doc_search_models(session_id, last_activity)

    def initialize_doc_search_models(self, session_id, last_activity):
       retriever, document_store = self.initialize_retriever()
       try:
           with self.initialization_lock:
               with self.session_lock:
                     self.session_data[session_id] = {
                    'retriever': retriever,
                    'document_store': document_store,
                    'last_activity': last_activity
                }
            self.models_initialized = True
        except Exception as e:
           print('Error', str(e))

    def load_doc_search_models_from_session(self, session_id):
        session_data = self.session_data.get(session_id)
        if session_data:
          self.initialized_retriever = session_data['retriever']
          self.initialized_document_store = session_data['document_store']
          self.initialized_last_activity = session_data['last_activity']


    def process_generative_session(self, query):
        if self.gen_models_initialized is True:
            self.load_gen_models_from_session()
        else:
            self.initialize_generative_models()

    def initialize_generative_models(self):
        retriever, document_store = self.initialize_retriever()
        prompt_node = self.initialize_prompt_node()
        try:
            with self.generative_data_lock:
                self.generative_data = {
                    'retriever': retriever,
                    'document_store': document_store,
                    'prompt_node': prompt_node
                }
            self.gen_models_initialized = True
            print('inside apps', self.generative_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error', str(e))

    def load_gen_models_from_session(self):
        #code of loading models
    
    
    def initialize_retriever(self):
        #code for retriever model

        return retriever, document_store

    def initialize_prompt_node(self):
        model_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'chatbot', 'downloaded_models', 'Llama7B')
        quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
            llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=False)

        if torch.cuda.is_available() and torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0) <= 14:
            self.device = torch.device('cuda:0')
            gpu = '15.0GB'
            model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path,
                                                          local_files_only=True,
                                                          device_map='auto',
                                                          torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                                                          load_in_8bit=True,
                                                          quantization_config=quantization_config,
                                                          max_memory={0: gpu})
    
            tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(
                model_path, local_files_only=True)

            lfqa_prompt = PromptTemplate(prompt="""generate an answer for the given question""", output_parser=AnswerParser())

            prompt_node = PromptNode(
                model_name_or_path=model_path,
                default_prompt_template=lfqa_prompt,
                max_length=1500,
                use_gpu=False,
                model_kwargs={"model": self.model,
                              "tokenizer": self.tokenizer,
                              'task_name': 'text2text-generation',
                              'device': None,
                              'stream': False}
            )

        return prompt_node
```

I can't find the generative_data that I created on initialize_generative_models function in apps.py. When I print in inside the function it shows the data but inside the views the dictionary is empty. The document search dictionary called doc below is my views:

```
def chatbot(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    # Ensure the session
    session_id = create_session(request)

    # Get parameters
    pipeline_type = request.GET.get('pipeline_type', '')
    query = request.GET.get('query', '')
    email = request.GET.get('email', '')
    feedback = request.GET.get('type', '')

    # Add incoming request to the queue
    if pipeline_type == 'generative':
        tuples = (request.session['session_id'],
                  query,
                  pipeline_type, 
                  request.session['last_activity'])
        print(tuples)
        ChatbotConfig.generative_queue.put(tuples)

        # Wait for the processing to complete
        ChatbotConfig.processing_complete_event.wait()

        print(ChatbotConfig.__dir__)

        if 'generative_data' in ChatbotConfig.__dict__:
            print(ChatbotConfig.__dict__)

            with ChatbotConfig.generative_data_lock:
                generative_data = ChatbotConfig.generative_data
                print('Generative data:', generative_data)  #generative data is empty
                if generative_data:
                    start_time = time.time()
                    retriever = generative_data['retriever']
                    prompt_node = generative_data['prompt_node']
                    document_store = generative_data['document_store']

                    if pipeline_type == 'generative':

                        try:
                            # Generative Q/A Pipeline
                            if prompt_node == None:
                                return JsonResponse({'smartelex_response': ['LLM model is already in use or the model is not loaded! Please try document']})
                            else:
                                result_queue = queue.Queue()

                                # Create a thread to process the pipeline
                                pipeline_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_pipeline, args=(
                                    query, retriever, prompt_node, result_queue))
                                pipeline_thread.start()

                                # Wait for the pipeline thread to finish
                                pipeline_thread.join()

                                # Get the prediction result from the queue
                                prediction = result_queue.get()


                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error',
                                                'message': str(e.args[0])
                                                 })

                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Generative data not found!'})
    elif pipeline_type == 'document_search':
        tuples = (request.session['session_id'],
                  pipeline_type, request.session['last_activity'])
        print(tuples)
        ChatbotConfig.document_queue.put(tuples)

        # Wait for the processing to complete
        ChatbotConfig.processing_complete_event.wait()

        print(dir(ChatbotConfig))

        # Retrieve the session data from the dictionary
        if 'session_data' in ChatbotConfig.__dict__:
            with ChatbotConfig.session_lock:
                session_data = ChatbotConfig.session_data.get(session_id)
                print('Inside views:', session_data)
                if session_data:
                    retriever = session_data['retriever']
                    document_store = session_data['document_store']
                    last_activity = session_data['last_activity']
                    # RUN DOCUMENT SEARCH PIPELINE



    return render(request, 'chatbot.html')
```

How to resolve this issue?